# Least Upper Bound

Tags: real-analysis

So I was reading in my book that the least upper bound does not necessarily have to be in the set of some numbers. How is this true? Could someone please give me an example to when the lub is not equal to the largest element in a set of numbers. In the book there is a question that asks to prove that the glb and lub are part of a set and I got confused when it said that because it just said that the glb and lub don't even need to be part of the set.

Comment: $1$ is the least upper bound for $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Randall but 1 is in the set for (0,1)

Comment: No it's not.  $(0,1) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 < x < 1\}$

Comment: Thanks @Randall

Comment: A sufficient condition for it being in the set is called "closed."

Comment: Another standard $\{1 - \frac 1n| n\in \mathbb N\} = \{0, \frac 12, \frac 23, \frac 34, \frac 45, ...\}$.

Comment: "A sufficient condition for it being in the set is called "closed." Sufficient be not necessary. $(0,1]$ is not closed.

Comment: " In the book there is a question that asks to prove that the glb and lub are part of a set" Part of *a* set? Or part of *every* set? It depends on the set. The lub of $(0,1]$ is part of the set $(0,1]$ but the lub of $(0,1)$ is not part of the the set.  That's not a contradiction because they are different sets.

Comment: OP's confusion might lie in the statement of the lub property:  it states that if $A$ is bounded above then its least upper bound exists in $\mathbb{R}$, but whether or not it's in $A$ is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The classic example of a set where the least upper bound (supremum) is not in the set is $\{-1/n|n\in\mathbb N\}$, whose supremum is 0 and not in the set.

The supremum and greatest lower bound (infimum) *may* independently be elements of the set for *some* sets, but not for others. The question that asks to show that those bounds are part of a set simply assures to you that they exist. In particular, those bounds are part of a set when the set is finite.

Comment: Hi @ParclyTaxel! In this statement *In particular, those bounds are part of a set when the set is finite*, did you assume that order over the set is total? I think bounds are not necessarily part of a set even though the set is finite in case the set is only partially ordered.

Comment: @Akira These are the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Some examples to help get the concepts down.

$1$ is the least upper bound for $A=(0,1)$ but $1 \notin A$.

$0$ is the greatest lower bound for $A=(0,1)$ but $0 \notin A$.

$1$ is the least upper bound for $B=(0,1]$ and $1 \in B$.

$0$ is the greatest lower bound for $B=(0,1]$ and still $0 \notin B$.

$1$ is the least upper bound for $C=[0,1]$ and $1 \in C$.

$0$ is the greatest lower bound for $C=[0,1]$ and $0 \in C$.

($C$ is an example of a closed set.)

$\sqrt{2}$ is the least upper bound for $D= \{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 \leq 2\}$ but $\sqrt{2} \notin D$.

$0$ is the greatest lower bound for $E=\{\frac{1}{n} : n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ yet $0 \notin E$.  $E$ is a good example of a set that isn't closed because it's missing the limit point $0$.